# How to instal rpy2 on mac OS - Library not loaded:

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, python-3.6, rpy2

This is proving to be very difficult on mac os and python3.

Below is are the paths for R.  I have them and pointed to them.  So why the problem?

From the command line:

1) which R

```
   /usr/local/bin/R
```

2)  R RHOME

```
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
```

In python:

```
    import os,sys
    sys.path.append('/usr/local/bin/R')
    sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources')
    os.environ['R_HOME'] = '/usr/local/bin/R'

    import rpy2.robjects as robjects

    from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import (baseenv,
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Here is the rpy2 version:

```
import rpy2
print(rpy2.__version__)
2.9.4
```

How I installed:

```
 pip3 install rpy2
```

Mac Version:

```
 10.14 Mojave
```

python3 version:

```
  which python3
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
```

R version:

```
R --version
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
```

Comment: So, you've focused on R being the issue but you haven't told us anything about the Python configuration. how you installed it? etc. There's a guess due to the error but my python 3.7 is not in `/Library`. We also don't know your macOS version. I grok the frustration (Python is the source of most if not all evil in the universe) but I think you need to provide more info to get aid.

Comment: Any luck with this?